# Bug for sending @ char to kannel

Tags: kannel

I have problem when I am send a message to kannel containing @ char.
  For example I sent "@ Test" but phone received something
  like "i Test".

Is this kannel bug? If so, does anybody have a patch for it?

Answer (score 9):

Problem with @ sign is quite popular in SMS because of this character in GSM has 0x00 code instead of 0x40 in ASCII or UTF-8.

To process this and some other characters correctly it's recommended to mention the following parameters when sending message through Kannel:

- *coding* - 0 (default GSM) or 2 (if you send Unicode characters)
- *charset* - character set of string you send to Kannel

This case Kannel will convert characters by it's own (if built with libiconv).

Example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?...&coding=0&charset=utf-8&text=test+@+sign
```

Another problem may happens if you connect to SMSC via SMPP. Some of platforms may use charset different from standard. For example it may be ASCII.

To resolve this you can use **alt-charset** parameter for proper **group = smsc** section of configuration file:

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
...
alt-charset = "ASCII"
```

To debug this I recommend to add logging for SMSC connection **log-level = 0** and check for protocol dumps to see what exactly is sent from Kannel to SMSC. Normally it should be 0x00 character for @ sign.

Comment: +1 for alt-charset switch. I was using coding':'1' for adjusting characters such as _, which differ between ISO and GSM. However, the same 1, is used for binary. So on the receiving side the encoding field was set to binary where as i expected ascii. Setting coding to 0, would adjust that to ascii and transfer values correctly except for characters such as _ or @